# Changing how returned json response looks

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to return a Json array and it works, but the other application I'm using the API for can't accept the format that the json is printed it (the way it looks, that is).

Example:

```
{
    "123": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But I need it to be:

```
"123":
{
    "id": 1
}
```

Using this code:

```
$param = 123;
$array = User::all();
return \Response::json([$param => $array], 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Is this possible to do somehow?

Comment: What you want isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is:

```
{
  "123": 
  {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

If you are sure you want to send just a single user, and not an array of users you can do:

```
$param = 123;
$user = User::first(); //Or any other Eloquent query, which gets the exact user you want

return response()->json([$param => $user]);
```